# What is an alternative to eval in this situation?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am pretty bad at stating my problem clearly. Sorry.

Basically, I have many view functions whose functionalities are very similar. Part of it is using `reverse`. However, each of those view functions execute different `reverse`, so I cannot write them one by one in my new "generic view". That's insane.

At the time, I am trying to reduce the amount of duplicated codes I am writing (that's over 500 lines of duplication!!!!!)

To solve this problem, I have a few helper functions, one of which is to evaluate `reverse` on whatever view function is given and whatever args are passed to the helper function.

```
def render_reverse(f, args):
    return eval(...)
```

But `eval` is evil, and is slow. Any substitute for `eval`? A better approach to solve this in Django?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you writing a function that does the same thing as `reverse`?

Comment: Could you give an example of what the `args` argument would look like?

Comment: Hi. Yes. I just updated my post. Hope that clear up why I am doing it. Thanks.

Comment: This is really hard to follow. From what I can tell the problem here runs deeper than just a simple use of eval.  Maybe you could explain more about what is the real end goal of this? And remove the Django stuff, I think it's just obfuscating the real issue.

Comment: @Keith Thanks. I re-edited my post. I am simply asking for either a substitute for `eval`, or Django-tricks (if any). Thanks.

Comment: @CppLearner Well, OK. One of the nice things about Python is that it's very good at "generic" programming. You almost never have to use `eval` for anything. One reason for this is that functions are also objects. You just call it: `f(*args)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to `eval` at all in the first place? Just call `reverse()` normally?

```
return reverse(f, *args)
```

[The `*` lets you unpack the argument list into actual args.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

---

That said, why do you need this helper at all? Why not just put `return reverse(...` in your view?

Comment: Thanks. I understand that. I just updated my post to reflect the purpose. I can't write 100 conditional statements and do each reverse. What if I have more reverse later? That's why I need to evaluate it, but `eval` is usually considered a bad practice, let alone my code doesn't work either.

Comment: thanks. It can grow. It can shrink. Why would I want to write them out if the goal is to cut down the amount of code? Then I don't evne need to bother writing anything, keep them the same lol.

Comment: You'd spend about the same number of characters writing out your dictionary as you would simply writing the view function in the first place.

Comment: Using your own wrapper function as simple syntactical sugar is going to confuse you later on when you want to maintain the code base.

Comment: Yes. I realize that. I was simply overthiniing. MY apology to Amber. Thanks for the help! Been bugging my head into mocking the last 2 days. ugh